# Why is the name of a process in /proc/PID/status not matching package name or ps command

Tags: kernel, process

A native application I wrote uses `/proc/PID/status` name variable. However, it appears that the name variable in the status file is incomplete. For example, when testing I opened the Android calculator and looked up the PID from PS and went to the corresponding `/proc/PID` folder. Then I cat the status file to see

```
Name: oid.calculator
```

The PS command shows `com.android.calculator`. `packages.xml` shows `com.android.calculator`. I tested on a few other phones (Razr Maxx running 4.0.4, Google Nexus running the same OS version) and noticed similar behavior.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is down to a Linux kernel feature: there are two different names for a process.

- One of the names is the last component of the path to the executable, e.g. `native_executable` if your application is located at `/data/apps/com.example.hello/native_executable`. This is the name that appears in the `Name` field of `/proc/PID/status`. The kernel truncates it to 15 characters, so in this case it contains `native_executab`.
- The other name is passed by the program that calls the application as its command line parameter #0 (`argv[0]` in C, `args[0]` in Java). This is the name that appears at the beginning of `/proc/PID/cmdline` and that `ps` shows.
- The path to the executable is also the target of the symbolic link `/proc/PID/exe`.

By convention, when a program starts another, it should use the name of the executable file as command line parameter 0, but it may choose to do otherwise. The `Name` field of `/proc/PID/status` is always set to the (truncated) name of the executable by the kernel.

This is a general Linux feature — see also [Can I use standard tools to get the full name of a process, when its name has embedded spaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21650/can-i-use-standard-tools-to-get-the-full-name-of-a-process-when-its-name-has-em) on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

The application itself can change both names afterwards (albeit there are length constraints). Dalvik uses this capability to distinguish between applications: all applications stem from the same native executable `/sytem/bin/app_process`; rather than let them all be called `app_process`, the VM changes both names to be the application package name. The name in `/proc/PID/status` is limited to 15 characters, which is why it's truncated. You can get the longer name from `/proc/PID/cmdline` (read up to the first null byte).

Comment: What is the reason to truncate Name to 15 characters? (TASK_COMM_LEN on `man proc`). Seems a pretty low limit.

Comment: @PabloBianchi It's truncated to keep the data structure constant-size, which is important in the kernel. I don't know why the size is that small.